# Is there a web framework for creating a review/rating website?

Tags: web-frameworks, review, rating-system

I am looking for creating something like mouthshut.com where users can rate products and services. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) - This question is much to  broad for stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a review/rating website with any web framework available over there...

The important thing is what programming language do you like to build it.

For Example: 
Python: Web2py, Django
Java/Scala: Play2, 
PHP: YII

A good place to begin: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks

Comment: I am a developer, so any programming language is okay.

Comment: I am a developer comfortable with multiple programming languages. Would like to know if there is a framework specifically for ratings website. Thanks.